# Pass flag from a python script to another

Tags: python, flask

Hello if i have a flag in one script, is it possible to pass real time change on others? I mean that, for example i wrote this script. let's name it `script1.py` which reads data from a serial communication and saves it to a  `.txt` file. When the `data` that i receive is `'0'` i would like to pass the `flag` `sent_json`  to `script2`. So when `script2` gets the trigger, POST the data. Any suggestions ?

```
while True:
            try :
                a = ser.readline()
                timestamped = str(datetime.datetime.now())
                suma = timestamped + "\t " + a.decode('utf-8')
                f = open("current_data.txt", 'a')
                f.write(suma)
                if (a.decode().strip() == '0'):
                    sent_json = True
                    saveData()
                    print("New data is saved!")

                sent_json = False
            except :
                print("Unexpected error: ")
                break
```

and i have another script, lets name it `script2.py`, in which is the main `Flask` app :

```
import sqlite3, json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from serialNumber_id import serial_number

import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def PostData():
    ''' Connect to DB, set the temperature to 2 decimal float, POST Data to DB'''

    with open("data.json") as dataFile:
        data = json.load(dataFile)


    for key, value in data.items():
        temperature = "{0:.2f}".format(float(value['data']))
        date = value['date']
        conn = sqlite3.connect('sensordata.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute( """INSERT INTO Temperature_data(temperature, currentdat, currenttime, device)  VALUES ((?) , (?), time("now"), (?))""", (temperature, date, serial_number))
        conn.commit()

open('data.json', 'w').close()

####### 
  Code something like 

    while True:
          if sent_json : 
             do something
          else:
              do something

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8181, debug=True)
```

Note that i have tried in `script2`

```
from script1 import sent_json
```

Also the scripts are in the same folder.

Comment: ...Why don't you just post the data when it's read?

Comment: @jpmc26 You mean when i read data from `ser.readline()` ? Because i do some kind of Processing

Answer (score 0):

So the absolute simplest thing to do, since you're polling anyway, is to write to some kind of shared resource like a file.  So `script1` writes something, maybe a timestamp, to a file, and `script2` continually polls that file to check to see whether it's changed.

Let me warn you that this, like anything that relies on the filesystem, is a terrible solution if you want performance or efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your suggestion. I thought of that as an answer, but as you said i did not like it because of efficiency. I am looking for something faster and 'more secure'. Imagine if the updates are very fast and the amount of data is huge, the script is gonna fail.  Thank you for your suggestion again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just POST the data to your flask app instead of trying to pass it from script to script?

```
#script1.py
import requests
my_data = {'name':'FooBar'}
requests.post('http://localhost:3000/', json=data)

#script2.py
from flask import request
...
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def PostData():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    print(data) 
    # {'name':'FooBar'}
    do_something(data)
```